Detailed derivation for the log likelihood of a logistic multinomial model
I am working with some Bayesian model development involving the logistic-normal multinomial model. However, I am quite confused about how to express the multinomial part.
Traditionally, the full likelihood for the multinomial logistic regression can be expressed through the softmax function over all individuals (i) and all categories (j), such as:
$$
P(y | X\beta) = \prod_i \prod_j \frac{\exp(x_i \beta_j)}{\sum_j \exp(x_i \beta_j)}^{y_{ij}}
$$
The log likelihood is then
$$
\sum_i \sum_j y_{ij}x_i \beta_j - \sum_i \sum_j y_{ij}\log(\sum_j \exp(x_i \beta_j))
$$
I have found in several resources that this last quantity can be expressed as:
$$
\sum_i \sum_j y_{ij}x_i \beta_j - \sum_i \log(\sum_j \exp(x_i \beta_j))
$$
However it is not clear how authors obtained the last expression. I feel that I miss some assumptions or tricks.
Can someone explain me how to obtain the last quantity or point to relevant resources please?

You have two nested $j$ variables in your likelihood. The likelihood is more correctly
$$\prod_i \prod_j \frac{\exp(x_i\beta_j)}{\sum_k \exp(x_i\beta_k)}$$
giving a loglikelihood
$$\sum_i\sum_j y_{ij}x_i\beta_j-\sum_i\sum_j y_{ij}\log\sum_k\exp(x_i\beta_k)$$
The log-sum-exp term is the same for a given $i$ and every $j$, so it can be passed through the $j$ sum
$$\sum_i\sum_j y_{ij}x_i\beta_j-\sum_i\left(\left(\log\sum_k\exp(x_i\beta_k)\right)\sum_j y_{ij}\right)$$
and now it's clear that the sum over $j$ for given $i$ is identically 1 and can be dropped.

Thanks. Can you elaborate on your last sentence please ?

@MangnierLoïc its cause for each $y_{i,j}$ corresponding to a given individual (i.e. with $i$ fixed), it only belongs to one class, i.e. there is only one variable $j$ where $y_{i,j}$ is nonzero. Hence, $\sum_{j} y_{i,j} = 0 + 0 + \ldots + 0 + 1 + 0 + \ldots + 0 = 1$.

Thanks @JohnMadden it is what I was thinking but not sure !
